# how to query the total count per skill

Tags: c#, sqlite

how to query the total count per skill.

I have 2 two table listed below;

```
TABLE: SkillList
+----------+
| Skills   | 
+----------+
| Skill_1  |
+----------+
| Skill_2  |
+----------+
| Skill_3  |
+----------+
| Skill_4  |
+----------+
| Skill_5  |
+----------+

TABLE: Skill Available (1/0 = true/false)
+----------+--------+---------+---------+---------+
| Username | Skill_1| Skill_2 | Skill_3 | Skill_4 |
+----------+--------+---------+---------+---------+
| Mark     | 1      | 1       | 1       | 1       |
+----------+--------+---------+---------+---------+
| Kent     | 1      | 0       | 1       | 0       | 
+----------+--------+---------+---------+---------+
| Mick     | 1      | 1       | 0       | 0       | 
+----------+--------+---------+---------+---------+
| John     | 1      | 1       | 0       | 0       | 
+----------+--------+---------+---------+---------+
```

I want to query the total count per skill by using the 2 tables above how could I achieved this result?

```
+-----------+-----------+
| SkillList |Total COUNT|
+-----------+-----------+
| Skill_1   | 4         | 
+-----------+-----------+
| Skill_2   | 3         | 
+-----------+-----------+
| Skill_3   | 2         |  
+-----------+-----------+
| Skill_4   | 1         | 
+-----------+-----------+
| Skill_5   | 0         |  
+-----------+-----------+
```

Comment: "Total count" is a unclear term. Do you mean how often that skill is picked by anyone? Also your design is wierd. There is one way to resolve N:M relationships and yours is exactly not the right one.

Comment: DB "designs" like that are flawed because it means adding a skill to the system requires changing the DB design as well as the code to interact with the table.  Research DB normalization.  The problem you are having would also go away.

Comment: Normally for many-to-many relationships, you have a `Users` table and a `Skills` table, then a table that combines them, like a `UserSkills` table that would contain `UserId` and `SkillId`. See [this article](https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-handle-a-many-to-many-relationship-in-datab) for more details.

Comment: @Jesson  After reviewing your latest questions, it's apparent that many of your database tables are designed like spreadsheets, but that will just lead to continued complications. As already commented, *normalization* is the key principle for designing tables.  All features of the database and SQL are designed for properly-normalized tables.  Shawn gave an answer that even included DDL to recreate normalized tables for your data.  Don't let your intuitive sense of visually appealing tables limit good design.  If necessary, data can be transformed back into spreadsheet-like tables for reports.

Answer (score 2):

The design of this table is way off, wich really just adds a load of issues. Skills and Characters are in a N:M realtionship and this is how you solve those:

Skill Available is a table with:

- ID, Integer, Primary Key
- FKUserID, Integer, Foreign Key from the user table
- FKSkillID, Integer, Foreign Key from the SkillList table

Then the answer is simple: `SELECT COUNT(SkillKey) WHERE SkillKey == @SkillKeyToCount` (Note that you can count anything, including *. It does not really mater outside of minor optimisations).

Comment: If you're going to recommend a new table, at least also include a valid query that fully represents the necessary join(s) to produce what the question asked for.  There is no FROM clause and where did SkillKey come from?  Something like `SELECT SkillList.Skills, Count(SkAv.FKSkillID) FROM [Skill Available] AS SkAv JOIN [SkillList] ON SkAv.FKSkillID = SkillList.ID GROUP BY SkillList.Skills`

Comment: @CPerkins: "where did SkillKey come from?" Extracted in the previous UI, because you would hardly ever bother asking for more then one of them? And for that rare case, you got the Union. Him writing a table for this was just *another* design mistake - never store process data.

Comment: Huh?  Previous UI?  Union?  Process data?